# Split an MySQL Array into Equal Parts

Tags: php, mysql, html-lists

I have some output from mySQL using PHP that looks something like this:

```
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 

    $menuDisplay = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];

        $menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel . '</a></li>';

    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query);
```

But I want to split my output between three UL, rather than containing it all in one UL. Any ideas how to do this?

To clarify:
I have this output with the above code:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

And I want this output:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

And if there's an uneven number of items, the last UL should just be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, as far as understood you , one way to solve the problem is   splitting the message to chunk of three "submessages" each time .I think the best option is creating an array , when each cell of it contains a single submessage. You might find this code helpful :

```
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 

    $menuDisplay = '';
    $output_count = 0 ; // count output
    $output_array = array () ; //every 3 loops we'll insert the output to this array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $output_count++ ; //update count value
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];
        $menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel .'</a></li>';
        array_push($output_array, $menuDisplay) ; // insert current message to array
    } 


$arrry_size = sizeof($output_array);
$count = 0 ;
$currentMessage = '' ;
for($i = 0 ; $i < $array_size ; $i++){
    $count ++ ;
    if($count >= $array_size / 3){
        echo $currentMessage ; //you could save it in an array or do whatever you want
        $currentMessage = '' ;
        $count = 0;
       }


   if($count == $array_size-1 ) // in case we've achieved the last index of the array
      echo currentMessage ;
   $currentMessage.= $output_array[$i];
}

    mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: This code will give me groups of three li, but what I need is to split my output into 3 equal groups of li tags.

To put it another way, I don't need 'n groups of three items', I need '3 groups of n items'.

Comment: I've updated the code , if you find it helpful please rate positive so others will be able to enjoy it :)